# Дана строка. Подсчитайте сколько раз в ней встречается каждый из ее символов

Tags: javascript

Подскажите что сделала на так?

```
//Дана строка. Подсчитайте сколько раз в ней встречается каждый из ее символов.
let str = 'hello',
    counter = {}; 
for ( let elem of str ) {
if ( counter[elem] == ' ' ) {
  counter[elem] =1;
} else counter[elem]++;
}
console.log(counter)
```

Код выдаёт:

// [object Object]
{
"h": null,
"e": null,
"l": null,
"o": null
}

Comment: Смотрите в консоли, что такое `counter[elem]` пот каждой итерации, также смотрите, равняется ли оно пробелу.

Comment: почему вы сравниваете с пробелом?

Comment: Underfined когда вводишь консоль ругается что не объявлена переменная ..

Comment: @ΝNL993 благодарю за подсказку. Помогло когда изменила на Null  от всего сердца 

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант:

```js
const str = "Hello";

const obj = [...str].reduce((obj, letter) =>
{
  obj[letter] = (obj[letter] ?? 0) + 1;
  
  return obj;
}, {})

console.info(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Дана строка. Подсчитайте сколько раз в ней встречается каждый из ее символов

Вот такой вариант можно использовать...

```js
const str = 'hello'
const m = [...str].reduce((m, v) => {
  const n = m.has(v) ?  m.get(v) + 1 : 1
  m.set(v, n)
  return m
} , new Map())
for (let a of m) console.log(a[0], a[1])
```